# Triggering different jenkins build in order

Tags: jenkins

I am trying to figure out an efficient way of triggering some builds on different branches in a set order.

My setup is that i have 4 separate builds that all link together but need to be run on set branches.

```
Database
Client
Cucumber Tests
Library
```

At the moment I can run these in a set order on say a master branch, each build triggering the next one if successful.

But what I want to achieve is say i make a commit to Cucumber Tests but need any of the other jobs on a different branch, how could i handle that and still in the required order. I have read that there is such a thing as a `Jenkins` file and I could specify branches in there ? if so how would i then trigger the other jobs on the relevant branches?

Hopefully this makes sense but any questions then please ask

Comment: Let me see if I understand.  You always want to run the four builds in the same order.  Each could potentially run in a different branch.  And you want to control the correspondence between builds and branches without having to modify the builds.  Is that right?

Comment: Hi, run builds in same order, yes.... each potentially run in different branch, yes..... the variation would be that any of the builds could start the process

Comment: Are there a fixed set of branches, or could any commit to any branch of any of the four builds start the process?

Comment: @user246 any commit to any of the four

Comment: @user246 any thoughts on this one at all please ?

Answer (score 1):

You can cause the completion of one build to trigger another.  You can also pass parameters to a build.

**(Edit)**

First, some terminology: I'll refer to each of Database, Client, Cucumber Tests, and Library as a *repository*.  A *job* is how Jenkins defines it: a runnable task controlled/monitored by Jenkins.  A *build* is an execution of a job.

**Two Schemes**

Two schemes for causing a version control commit to start a build would be Push and Pull.  *Push* means the version control system takes an action that causes Jenkins to start a build.  *Pull* means Jenkins polls the version control system for changes that justify starting a build.

Each scheme starts with creating a job with four parameters, one per build.  Each parameter specifies a branch name.

**Push**

In a Push scheme, a build would be launched by a commit hook in the version control system.   For example, if the OP uses Git, they can use the post-commit hook to determine which branch had changed and then issue an HTTP request to Jenkins to launch the build.

That assumes there is network connectivity between the committer and Jenkins, and that any Jenkins access control issues can be worked out.
If access control is not a problem but there is no network connectivity, it may be possible for commit hook to post a build request to an intermediary, and then for the intermediary to cause Jenkins to launch a build.

**Pull**

The goal for the Pull system would be to configure Jenkins to poll for changes in all branches of four repository.  Jenkins has a [Multiple SCMs Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Multiple+SCMs+Plugin) that might do what you want.  The documentation says the plugin was deprecated in favor of the [Pipeline Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Pipeline+Plugin).  You might try looking at that too.

Another option would be to create four "launcher" jobs, one per repository.  Each launcher job would poll the version control system for changes in its corresponding repository.  The [Git Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin) supports polling all branches.  When it detects change, it would launch a build with the appropriate branch information.  You will have to research how to determine *which* specific branch has changed.

Comment: Hi, yes i understand this, but what if i make a commit to `cucumber tests` which is normally triggered third in the sequence but i need `database` to be on a particular branch, I need to ensure that the order of builds goes like `database, client, cucumber tests, library`. How would that be achieved